# How to fix "The argument type 'Future<int>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'int'" in Flutter

Tags: listview, flutter, dart, future

I am returning the count of rows from a table and trying to use it as itemCount in listview builder. But listview builder is showing this error

```
The argument type 'Future<int>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'int'
```

How to fix that?

Comment: Please post a code snippet so people will be able to assist you @Shahbaz

Answer (score -1):

Change the return type of the method to Future instead of int.